# Manim: FadeToColor vs. animate.set_color

Tags: python, animation, jupyter-notebook, manim

I'm starting with this scene from a [tutorial](https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/ManimCE-tutorial/blob/main/_02_basic_animations.py).

```
class BasicProgression(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text = Text("Hello word")
        self.play(Write(text))
        self.play(text.animate.set_color(RED))
        self.wait()
```

From what I understand, the 2nd last line could be replaced with `self.play(text.animate.set_color(RED))`.

What is the difference, if there is any? Is one method faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's just a shorthand notation:

https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/_modules/manim/animation/transform.html#FadeToColor